# Creating new dataframe by replacing existing dataframe one column at a time affects existing dataframe. How do I stop this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem where I am creating a new dataframe that has the exact structure of another dataframe, except that I am adjusting each value through a series of iterations.

```
new_samples = more_samples
for statistic in ['PPG', 'RPG', 'APG', 'BPG', 'SPG', 'Triple_Doubles', 'PTS', 'REB', 'AST', 'BLK', 'STL']: 
    # This will iterate through every single position so that we can automatically update the entire more_samples df.
    array_of_new_values = []
    # This resets after each stat has replaced the previous stat column.
    for era_index in range(0, 11):
        # This will iterate through the index of every 'Era' in a previously defined function array_of_eras to check if
        # if a player belongs to an era.
        player_index = 0
        # This resets after each Era has their respective statistic appended to the array of new values to check through
        # every player once more.
        for time in new_samples['Era']:
            # This is simply going to iterate through the Era column to check for every player's era.
            if time == array_of_eras[era_index]:
                # If the player's era matches with the era that is in the current index of the second for loop, we adjust 
                # the states.
                array_of_new_values = np.append(array_of_new_values, more_samples[statistic][player_index] * min(1.2, adjustment1(statistic)[era_index]))
                player_index += 1
            else:
                player_index += 1
                # We add one to the player_index after each player has been checked.
    new_samples[statistic] = array_of_new_values 
    # After the complete array of new values replaces the statistic of the previous df, we move on to the next one.
```

The problem is that after I run this function, the existing dataframe is affected in the exact same way as the new dataframe is. So now I just have two adjusted dataframes and no original one unless I go back in the code and rerun the functions that made the original dataframe.

How can I prevent this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the first dataframe first, and run your operations on this copy.

```
df_new = df.copy()
```

This creates a new dataframe in a different location, so any changes to `df_new` are not reflected on `df`